# Get the current site_id when using a model in Django

Tags: django

With Django I can use the `OneToOneField` like this to create a relationship:

```
user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User')
```

How can I make a model (example below) that would get the current site_id when trying to upload an image:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    site = # something here
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='headers')
    image_thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='image', processors=[ResizeToFit(1920)], format='JPEG', options={'quality': 90})
    image_admin_thumb = ImageSpecField(source='image', processors=[ResizeToFit(300)], format='JPEG', options={'quality': 80})
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: What is the "current site id"? what is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Sayse the current site id would be what site the user is logged in to. The user then uploads an image "through" that site and the site would be that current id. I use the Mezzanine CMS for Django.

Answer (score 3):

You can do one of 2 things:

1. You can use the `get_current_site` shortcut, but this would require the `request` object
2. You can get the Site object from `settings.SITE_ID` - this would need an additional lookup though.

For the second case, the usage would be something like this:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.conf import settings

def set_current_site():
    return Site.objects.get(pk=settings.SITE_ID)
```

and in the models:

```
site = models.ForeignKey(Site, default=set_current_site)
```

Comment: I got the error when trying to migrate: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Site'`

Comment: what is `settings.SITE_ID` set to ?